# How do I make .gitlab-ci.yml execute different ansible playbooks in different folders/subfolders?

Tags: ansible, gitlab

I just started learning about [NetDevOps](https://www.packetcoders.io/what-is-netdevops/).

All the examples containing demos of GitLAb + Ansible show how to execute "`deploy.yml`" from Ansible from the `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

However, when I see a general network equipment based Ansible tutorial the author executes different Ansible cookbook `.yml` files, for example `sites.yml` from the root, `deploy.yml` from another subfolder, `interfaces.yml` from another subfolder.

Can someone give me an example of how I would execute the different Ansible playbook `.yml` files on demand?

I.e. - When it detects changes in `.yml` in a folder, run that `.yml` file under that folder?

Comment: Take a look at `rules:changed` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) to have specific jobs being launched when a specific file changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have an ansible repo and a .gitlab-ci.yml in the root of it.

```
.gitlab-ci.yml
ansible/cookbook1
ansible/cookbook2
```

For each cookbook you could create a Gitlab job

```
execute_cookbook1:
 script: 
  - ...ANSIBLE COMMANDS...
 ...
 only:
     changes: 
       - ansible/cookbook1/**/*.yml
    
execute_cookbook2:
 script: 
  - ...ANSIBLE COMMANDS...
 ...
 only:
     changes: 
       - ansible/cookbook2/**/*.yml
```

This way when you push your code to ansible repo, Gitlab will detect which cookbook changed. And run the according job

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your GitLab job [complex rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#complex-rules) like `if`, `changes`, and `exists`, in the same rule.
The rule evaluates to `true` only when all included keywords evaluate to `true`.

> For example:
>
> ```yaml
> docker build:
>  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
>  rules:
>    - if: '$VAR == "string value"'
>      changes:  # Include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
>        - Dockerfile
>        - docker/scripts/*
>      when: manual
>      allow_failure: true
> ```

In your case, keep `when: manual` and `changes: *.yml` in order to trigger the job manually, if `yml` Ansible playbook are changed.

Comment: I would've also liked to check this as the answer also but they don't let me check on both solutions.  btw - where does the variables come from (in the if statement above)?  Also what does manual mean?  I tried reading the docs, but most of it it didn't make sense to me (most were docker examples which I don't work with.)

Comment: @JuniorPenguin No worries, you have selected the right one. The variable comes from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html. And manual is explained in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually. The job only runs if it was started manually by a user, not if it was called by another job, or automatically scheduled.